# JAXB2 Maven Plugin ignores specified element names and file name when generating XSD file

Tags: jaxb2-maven-plugin

I want to generate an XSD file from a Java file using the JAXB2 Maven plugin. But JAXB generates a file that ignores the names specified in the @XmlElement annotations and does not rename the file. Instead it just says "[WARNING] SimpleNamespaceResolver contained no localNamespaceURI; aborting rename.".

My Java class looks like this:

```
package com.my.testpackage;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    namespace = "https://my.test.domain",
    propOrder = {
        "Entries"
    })
@XmlRootElement(
    namespace = "https://my.test.domain",
    name = "TestXmlClass"
)
public class TestXmlClass {

  @XmlElement(name = "Entries")
  protected List<String> entries;

  public List<String> getEntries() {
    return entries;
  }

  public TestXmlClass setEntries(List<String> entries) {
    this.entries = entries;
    return this;
  }
}
```

The package-info.java looks like this:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "https://my.test.domain")
package com.my.testpackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

The Maven plugin config looks like this:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schemagen</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>schemagen</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>src/main/java/com/my/testpackage/TestXmlClass.java
            </source>
        </sources>
        <transformSchemas>
            <transformSchema>
                <uri>https://my.test.domain</uri>
                <toFile>my-xsd-file.xsd</toFile>
            </transformSchema>
        </transformSchemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

The output is named schema1.xsd and not my-xsd-file.xsd and it writes the element names in lower case instead of upper case and it ignores the namespace from the Java annotations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="testXmlClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="entries" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I am running into exact same issue. did you find any solution?

Comment: Using an older version (2.X) worked for me to resolve most of the issues I was having with JAXB. Version 3.X feels broken in many ways.

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing the jaxb dependencies from the pom and let the plugin download the dependencies.